# Count Number of Occurrences in PowerApps Collection

Tags: collections, powerapps, powerapps-collection

I am trying to count the number of occurrences of each item in a PowerApps Collection.

SharePoint List Name: Product

Desired Result

```
Fruit    Number of Occurrences
Apple            1
Orange           1
Apple            2
Banana           1
Orange           2
Apple            3
Banana           2
Banana           3
Watermelon       1
Apple            4
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `GroupBy` to do the grouping by *Fruit* and `AddColumns`to add a new column to store the group count.

Assuming you are planning to display the above in a **Vertical Gallery**, you can use this formula in the *Items* property:

`AddColumns(GroupBy(Product, "Fruit", "Grouped"), "FruitCount", CountRows(Grouped))`

Please see a screenshot below. I am using Departments instead of Fruits, but the concept is the same.

[image]

Comment: Where do I put this? Can I add this to the clearcollect code? Please point me in the right direction

Comment: I updated my answer. Please have a look to see if it is clearer now.

Comment: I don't think you understand what I am trying to accomplish. I do not want to group the data in the collection. In my example below I want to show every record in the collection and display the number of occurrences of each item in the collection.

Fruit    Number of Occurrences
Apple            1
Orange           1
Apple            2
Banana           1
Orange           2
Apple            3
Banana           2
Banana           3
Watermelon       1
Apple            4

Answer (score 0):

Althouh it might not be what Kendall was after... Thanks, this was really useful.

You can then also order the Gallery by the Count, in the case below, in descending order.
SortByColumns(AddColumns(GroupBy(Product, "Fruit", "Grouped"), "FruitCount", CountRows(Grouped)),"FruitCount",SortOrder.Descending)